# android setting textview from another class with Fragments

Tags: android, class, android-fragments, textview

I'm trying to set a textview text from another class
the textview is in the main activity and i need to set it from another class thats not an activity

In the past I have used the following

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
public static TextView textViewObj1;
public static TextView textViewObj2;
public static TextView textViewObj3;
public static TextView textViewObj4;
public static TextView textViewObj5;


public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textViewObj1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sitename);
    textViewObj2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Building);
    textViewObj3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Floor);
    textViewObj4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Roomno);
    textViewObj5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Drawref);
```

I then set it in the other class by using

```
    DemoActivity.textViewObj1.setText(c.getString(1));
    DemoActivity.textViewObj2.setText(c.getString(2));
    DemoActivity.textViewObj3.setText(c.getString(3));
    DemoActivity.textViewObj4.setText(c.getString(4));
    DemoActivity.textViewObj5.setText(c.getString(5));
```

The problem I have is the app im trying to set it for uses fragments and so the main activity instead of starting like this

```
  public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
```

Starts like this

```
  public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

for some reason when I try to set the textview from the other class using

```
DemoActivity.textViewObj5.setText(c.getString(5));
```

It gives the error : DemoActivity cannot be resolved

Any Ideas?

Your help is as always appreciated

Mark

Comment: You cannot refer to the views as static since your views in `DemoActivity` are only created when an instance of `DemoActivity` is created.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. It Works when your use Extends Activity fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is:

1) Define a listener interface in your fragment

```
public interface FragmentInteractionListener{
   void onFragmentInteraction(String textToPut);
}
```

2) Implement this interface in your parentActivity:

```
public class MyParentActivity extends Activity implements FragmentInteractionListener {
...

   @Override
   public void onFragmentInteraction(String textToPut) {
      //Update the textView here
   }
```

3) In your fragment, call the parent Activity method:

```
((FragmentInteractionListener )getActivity()).onFragmentInteraction("This is the new text");
```

You may want to check if the parent activity is implementing the required interface in fragment's onAttach() method

Comment: Thank you so much while i didnt use n interface it made me understand fragments better which enabled me to make my existing code work

Answer (score 0):

Try Using DemoActivity.getActivity() or this.getActivity(). I know that when using an activity, we just call the context, but using fragments involves using getActivity.Hope this helps

Comment: I tried using DemoActivity.getActivity().textViewObj1.setText(c.getString(1)); but it stillsays it cant be resolved